# How do I find and remove invisible/hidden caption in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

I noticed that my auto-numbering for Figure captions skips one.  When I create a table of figures, it mentions the missing one.  I ctrl click on it to go there, but I don't see where the caption could be.  I want to get rid of this caption but there is no way I can select it.  I just know it exists (and approximately where it exists) by the Table of Figures.  How to delete such a caption?

And to note, it looks like by Find that this is located in a Textbox, but I can't find the missing TextBox.  Maybe it is a matter of locating an invisible text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is likely the hidden caption is under one of your figures in a text box

On the **Home tab** activate the **Selection Pane** and use that to find the caption.

[image: screenshot]

Once you have the text box selected, you can move it, change its wrapping, or delete it and create a new Caption.

---

**Note** that it is *possible* to have the caption not be in a text box but under the figure. *This would be very rare.* If the figure is inserted in-line-with-text then the caption also will be, but the figure will not be able to positioned on top of the caption unless wrapping is later changed.

If this has happened, you would need to find the caption using your Table of Figures to take you to the page, and move the figure so it does not occlude the in-line caption.

Here is [my writing on keeping figures and captions together](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#MovingFigureCaption).

Comment: I like this approach.  I do a search on Figure 39 (the figure that is hidden) click on the Textbox result in that and then open the selection pane and see there are two text boxes: Text Box 6 and Text Box 7 associated with that item.  Unfortunately, I can't see them on screen, but if I carefully select and push delete button, it looks like it takes care of the problem.  Have to see if the rest of my document is still there